# What is the etymology of the word "dinlo"?

Tags: etymology, british-english, offensive-language

**dinlo**  n. *stupid person; idiot*

Suggested etymology from urban dictionary

> a Romany (gypsy language) word that has been adopted widely by the east coast.

Sorry if this language offends but I think it is necessary that I post the actual sentence in which I saw it, and in any case the word is probably itself quite offensive already.

> Christ, could you sound like any more of a fuckin **dinlo** in one thread?

I would love to know if this really is Romany.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it seems to be so. The [Webster's Online Dictionary](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.org/Romani/dinlo) definitely agrees. It seems that "dinlo" is a Romany word meaning "stupid", and it has just been directly "loaned" into English in some places (not mine, as far as I know)

In the link provided, the words "stupid" and "silly" have been translated into Romani as "dinlo", while the Romani word "dinlo" has been translated into English, meaning, "silly, stupid, an idiot, a fool".

Edit: It seems the above wasn't enough proof, so I looked up a [Romani-English Dictionary](http://www.freelang.net/online/romani.php?lg=gb), and the translation given was:

> dinlo -> stupid

Comment: I didn't think to look there but tbh I'm not sure I trust that source as an authority.  It's helpful but it doesn't settle it yet.

Comment: It's Websters...?

Comment: "Webster's Dictionary refers to the line of dictionaries first developed by Noah Webster in the early 19th century, and also to numerous unrelated dictionaries that added Webster's name just to share his prestige. The term is a genericized trademark for comprehensive dictionaries of the English language."

Comment: Ah yep. Something to look out for there. However, I hope my new addition might help